# Inline a common method

Tags: rust, inline

I want to inline `TraitA::x()` method without knowing who implements `TraitA`.

For example:

(Note: `StructB` implements `TraitA`.)

```
let a: &TraitA = &StructB { x: 0f32 };
a.x(); // This should access `a.x` field directly
       // as `TraitA::x()` always return the same field,
       // the same `b.x` field slot.
```

The method will be implemented the same way in different structs.

```
trait TraitA {
    fn x(&self) -> f32;
}

struct StructB {
    x: f32
}

impl TraitA for StructB {
    #[inline]
    fn x(&self) -> f32 {
        self.x
    }
}
```

Will `a.x()` get inlined to `(a as &StructB).x`?

I can do this fine on C++, for example:

```cpp
class A {
    float _x;

public:
    float x() {
        return _x;
    }
};

struct B : A {};

int main() {
    A* a = new B;
    a->x();
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure: you want to inline that trait method call so that it's as cheap/fast as a simple field access of a concrete type, correct?

Comment: It's highly unclear what you are asking. You say *without knowing who implements `MyTrait`* but then you put `#[inline]` on a concrete implementation. you also say *will be implemented the same way in different structs* but I fail to see what relevance that has to the question.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Yes, just that. You can do this in C++ too, but it looks like Rust works another way.

Comment: @Shepmaster I know it doesn't make sense, but I'm really unsure what I should do to make this method inline. Will it just inline fine anyways?

Comment: @yugioh "You can do this in C++" -- it would be helpful if you could add C++ code to your question that shows what you want to achieve =)

Comment: @yugioh your c++ code is illegal as far as I know...

Comment: @KorelK It's legal after 21m ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confusing a few things here. First of all: **it's impossible to inline a method from a trait when you are using it in purely virtual context** (that is: you have no information about the actual type). This would look like this:

```
fn unknown_type(foo: &MyTrait) -> f32 {
    foo.x()
}
```

Here, the compiler can't possibly know the actual type behind the trait object `foo`. Thus, it is forced to use the vtable and do dynamic dispatch to call the method. There is an optimization called *devirtualization* that tries to guess the correct type to do static dispatch (or even inline the method), but this optimization has its limits.

> Will `a.x()` get inlined to `(a as &StructB).x`?

In most cases yes, but this has nothing to do with your inline-attribute nor with trait objects. In your tiny example, the compiler can see the whole function and knows that `a` has the underlying type `StructB`. But again, this is not a purely virtual context: the compiler has type information it can use.

---

Another thing: this all has nothing to do with `final` in Java/`f` in C# -- as mentioned in [the first version of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51698722/1).

These keywords are only useful for class hierarchies. Since you can, in principle, override all methods of every class in Java/C# in a derived class, the compiler could in theory never inline or statically dispatch a method. It would always have to check the vtable to check if there is a more specialized version of this method. When the compiler has a variable of a class that declares that method as `final`, it can statically call it, since it is guaranteed that it's not overridden.

But having a trait object in Rust is (regarding this question) equivalent to having a variable with an interface type. And you (clearly) cannot declare an interface method as `final`. So here, the compiler has to do virtual dispatch regardless of whether some implementing classes declare their implementation as `final`.

---

Furthermore, your C++ doesn't have anything to do with what you're asking. The base class `A` declares a non-virtual function with a method body. That means that the function will never be callable in virtual context. But in your Rust code `x()` does not have a body and can be used in virtual context.

In Rust there is nothing like that, but you could add methods to the trait object via `impl Trait { ... }`. Implementors of that trait are not able to override those methods, so the compiler can do static dispatch or inline the method easily.

You can see that example with its assembly [here](https://godbolt.org/g/KB3Z49).

---

To answer what I think you are actually asking:

> You want to inline that trait method call so that it's as cheap/fast as a simple field access of a concrete type, right?

That's, again, not possible in purely virtual context. When the compiler doesn't know the implementing type, it cannot generate a simple field access, since it doesn't know the offset of that field from the base pointer! I mean, not all implementing types are guaranteed to have the same memory layout and keep `x` at always the same position.

*However*, one could do better than a method: instead of calling the getter method, it would be possible to store the field offset in the vtable and use that to index the field. That would still be more expensive than a standard field access, but faster than a method call.

That's exactly what's proposed in [this RFC: "Allow fields in traits that map to lvalues in impl'ing type"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1546). The RFC thread is closed, but the RFC is still developing.

So you can't do that now. Using a trait method is the best you can do right now.

Comment: I would note that if one finds themselves frequently invoking a virtual method and the resulting optimization-barrier is a bottleneck, one solution is to move the virtual *upward*, which should reduce the number of virtual calls.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Can #[inline] be used in both trait method declarations and implementations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733424/can-inline-be-used-in-both-trait-method-declarations-and-implementations) and [this thread on the language forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/trait-method-inlining/16817), it is impossible to tell the compiler that *all* implementations of a particular method should be inlined. However, since Rust is statically typed, traits can be disambiguated at compile time, so I see no reason the Rust compiler shouldn't be able to inline specific method implementations. I can't tell you for certain whether it will actually do so, since `#[inline]` attributes are merely suggestions which the compiler is free to ignore, but that would be true even if we were talking about stand-alone functions instead of methods. In other words, inlining methods should be possible, but you should never rely on your function being inlined under any circumstances.

Comment: "particular method should be inlined. However, since Rust is statically typed, traits can be disambiguated at compile time, so I see no reason the Rust compiler shouldn't be able to inline specific method implementations" You're talking about traits as generic parameter bounds. There are also `dyn` use cases.